# keyboard showing lately when i press edittext and also take time when i press the back button

Tags: android

When I edit text it takes some time to appear the keyboard, in my layout list view is there, without list view its coming quickly, with list view its taking time to appear. If I give give list view size manually it is working correctly.

[image: keyboard back press issue when I use list view]

thanks in advance guys
I tried with adjust span and all but still I am getting the same problem and also get the height of the keyboard and all but here also the same problem

Comment: Pleaes post your code, and with what are you testing? Emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You are testing your application on Emulator, Please run your project on Android Phone so the problem you are facing will not be there.